# Suppose that $X_1\sim \exp(1)$ and $X_2\sim \exp(1)$ and $X_1, X_2$ are independent. Find the pdf of $T=X_1+X_2$.

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics

Suppose that $X_1\sim \exp(1)$ and $X_2\sim \exp(1)$ and $X_1, X_2$ are independent. Find the pdf of $T=X_1+X_2$.

My solution is as follows.
$$
P(T\le t)=P(X_1+X_2\le t)=\int\int_C e^{-x_1-x_2}dx_1dx_2
$$
where $C=\{x_1>0, x_2>0, x_1+x_2\le t\}$.

Then
$$
=\int_0^t \int_{x_1=0}^{t-x_2} e^{-x_1-x_2}dx_1dx_2=\int_0^t e^{-x_2}\int_0^{t-x_2} e^{-x_1}dx_1 dx_2
$$
$$
=\int_0^t e^{-x_2}(-e^{-t+x_2}+1)dx_2=-te^{-t}-e^{-t}+1
$$
for $t>0$.

Is there any error in my solution? Thanks!

Comment: Do you know what $\operatorname{Exp}(\lambda)$ means?

Comment: The probability densities for $X_1$ and $X_2$ are $e^{-x_1}$ and $2 e^{-2 x_2}$, respectively. You neglected the normalizing coefficients and one of your exponents is off.

Comment: @K.Jiang Sorry, that is my typo $X_2\sim \exp(1)$ but not $\exp(2)$. Is my solution right now?

Comment: How many times will ‘What is the distribution of $X \pm Y$, etc.,’ be tolerated at MSE as a matter of course?

Comment: To denote the exponential probability distribution and not the exponential function, you should use a capital E, e.g $\operatorname{Exp}$ (`\operatorname{Exp}`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $X_1$ and $X_2$ are absolutely continuous and admit probability densities, so too does $T:=X_1+X_2$, and we may compute the density of $T$ by convolution - for $t>0$ we have
\begin{align}
f_T(t) &= (f_{X_1}\star f_{X_2})(t)\\
&= \int_{\mathbb R} f_{X_1}(s)f_{X_2}(t-s)\ \mathsf ds\\
&= \int_0^t e^{-s}2e^{-2(t-s)}\ \mathsf ds\\
&= 2e^{-2t}\int_0^t e^s\ \mathsf ds\\
&= 2e^{-t}(1-e^{-t}).
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you! Can we get the result by using my method without convolution ?

Comment: Sorry, that is my typo $X_2\sim \exp(1)$ but not $\exp(2)$. Is my solution right now?

Answer (score 1):

As you asked in the comment to Math1000's solution, the same may be found without convolution by instead relying on the characteristic function (cf). For $X\sim \operatorname{Exp}(\lambda)$, the cf is given by

\begin{equation}
\varphi_X(t) = \frac{\lambda}{\lambda-it}
\end{equation}

Then for $T=X_1+X_2$, one has $\varphi_T(t) = \varphi_{X_1}(t)\varphi_{X_2}(t)$. After you changed to both random variables having the same rate ($\lambda=1$), this gives that

\begin{equation}
\varphi_T(t) = \left( \frac{\lambda}{\lambda-it} \right)^2 
\end{equation}

which can be identified as the cf of a Gamma distribution. In case of the rate not being the same, the resulting distribution is that of the Generalized Integer Gamma distribution. In either case, you can also invert $\varphi_T(t)$ to obtain the pdf of $T$.

Comment: No. I mean calculate it by integral.

Comment: The inversion of the cf into a pdf is an integral as the cf is related to the Fourier transform. Knowing some common cf:s does however simplify things as one doesn't have to go about solving the inverse Fourier transform every time.